# Trigger breath-app or HRV measurement programmatically [Apple Watch 4]

Tags: ios, swift3, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I want to trigger a HRV-measurement on my Apple Watch 4 programmatically. Is there a way to start the breath-app from my own app in background to trigger the HRV measurement? Or is it possible to trigger a HRV-measurement directly?

If not is there even an alternative to measure stress in nearly realtime programmatically on my Apple Watch 4 ?

Please provide me some Code examples if you know an answer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to trigger an HRV measurement on Apple Watch. You should file a radar with Apple to request one.

Comment: Is there another way to get the stress level nearly in realtime of the person, that wears the watch?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to launch the Breathe app programmatically, but heart rate variability is [accessible from HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier/2881127-heartratevariabilitysdnn).

Comment: Yeah thats true but the HRV is only triggered once the day automatically. And with that, i cant determine the stress level in nearly real time.